# Realm DB ios swift. Get number of occurances of a keyword in List

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have an object as below

```
@objcMembers class MyObject: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    dynamic var myArray = List<MyArray>()
}

class MyArray: Object {
    @objc dynamic var number = 0
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
}
```

How can I get number of occurrences of a keyword in *text*.

Suppose *text* contain sentences like

1. This world is very beautiful. This is correct
2. This is a beautiful car

So if I search for *This*, I should get 3.
If I search for *beautiful*, I should get 2

Comment: This would be done with a filter but are the sentences 1. and 2. in different objects or in the same object? e.g. `let text = "This world is very beautiful. This is correct. This is a beautiful car" is three sentences in one text property. Or are you stating the MyArray Object has a text property that will contain 1. And then a separate MyArray property text with 2. Furthermore, are you asking how to retrieve that from the List property in MyObject or will there be many MyObjects?

Comment: myArray will be an array of many objects. .I refer to sentences as different objects.
Like index 0 of array is This world is very beautiful. This is correct
Index 1 of array is This is a beautiful car. When I am using a filter, I am getting 2 as count. I am not getting 3 count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do it to modify the code to make it more readable.

List properties are defined [like this](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-cheatsheet) and I also changed the property name to better match what it is (not an array)

```
class MyObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let textList = List<TextClass>() //fixed definition
}
```

while we're at it, lets update the object stored in that list with a better fitting class name

```
class TextClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var number = 0
    @objc dynamic var text = ""
}
```

And then here's the code to read in all of the MyObject objects, iterate over the textList property and count the total amount of occurrences of a given word.

```
let myObjectResults = realm.objects(MyObject.self)

let wordToFind = "This" //the word to find
for obj in myObjectResults {
    var count = 0
    let theList = obj.textList
    for textObj in theList {
        let wordCount = textObj.text.lowercased().components(separatedBy: wordToFind.lowercased()).count - 1
        count += wordCount
    }
    print("object: \(obj.name) had: \(count) occuranced of string: \(wordToFind)")
}
```

and the results when searching for the word 'This'

```
object: some object had: 3 occurrences of string: This
```

When searching for the word Beautiful here's the output

```
object: some object had: 2 occurrences of string: Beautiful
```

The reason we're using iteration in the case is because we're actually performing a substring search of the realm property `text`. While Realm filtering is great at returning Results objects where objects property(s) match a particular query, it's not great at internal string manipulation.

There may be an NSPredicate solution as well.